# Adding elements to a dictionary via for loop

Tags: python, dictionary, append

Python 3.6

All debug output is from PyCharm 2017.1.2

I have a program that is working with one flaw.

Here is the piece I am having a problem with:

```
def striplist(errlist):
    return [item.strip() for item in errlist]

for line in shintlist:
    errors_list = striplist(line.split(","))

    errRegex = re.compile(r'(\d+)(\s)(\D+)')

    errdict = {}
    for elem in errors_list:
        mo = errRegex.search(elem)
        errdict[mo.group(3)] = int(mo.group(1))
        if int(mo.group(1)) > 0:
            print("There are errors")
        else:
            print("There are no errors")

    print(errdict)
```

** NOTE** The print statements are just for me to use at this time
to check the program logic.  They will be removed later.

At the time these instructions execute, 'shintlist'
is a list of comma separated strings.

```
__len__ = {int} 9
0 = {str} '     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored'
1 = {str} '     0 watchdog'
2 = {str} '     0 input packets with dribble condition detected'
3 = {str} '     5912 packets output, 738736 bytes, 0 underruns'
4 = {str} '     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 2 interface resets'
5 = {str} '     4 unknown protocol drops'
6 = {str} '     0 babbles, 0 late collision, 0 deferred'
7 = {str} '     0 lost carrier, 0 no carrier'
8 = {str} '     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out'
```

The above code works.  It correctly splits on the ',' and then strips
off the white space.  It then creates a dictionary key:value
entry in errdict{}:

```
errdict = {dict} {'input errors': 0}
 __len__ = {int} 1
 'input errors' (64451912) = {int} 0
```

Where I am stuck is this:  With each iteration errdict{} is overwritten
with the next line from 'shintlist'.

What I want to do is:

If every single value is zero (0) for every single individual item:
    if int(mo.group(1)) > 0:
then skip this interface.  If ANY one value is greater than zero then
I want the dictionary 'errdict{}' to contain ALL of the above lines
from 'shintlist' so I have a single dictionary with everything.

** NOTE 2** These entries: 5912 packets output, 738736 bytes, will always
be non-zero for an active interface.  I will deal with these later.

Each of these lines is the state of errdict{} when each line in 'shintlist'
is processed:

```
{'input errors': 0, 'CRC': 0, 'frame': 0, 'overrun': 0, 'ignored': 0}
{'watchdog': 0}
{'input packets with dribble condition detected': 0}
{'packets output': 6304, 'bytes': 786190, 'underruns': 0}
{'output errors': 0, 'collisions': 0, 'interface resets': 2}
{'unknown protocol drops': 4}
{'babbles': 0, 'late collision': 0, 'deferred': 0}
{'lost carrier': 0, 'no carrier': 0}
{'output buffer failures': 0, 'output buffers swapped out': 0}
```

I want a single dictionary with all lines and values if any single value is
non-zero so I can print off a report showing all interfaces with errors.

Unless I am way off, I am asking how do append each line to
errdict{} instead of overwriting?

Thank you.

Comment: dkv, I owe you a beer!!  This is a work in progress and the previous version of my program was more 'linear' -- the logic did not use a loop: I just tested with a single line to make sure the function and list comprehension worked.  Then I added the loop and put errdict{} inside the loop.  I'm still basically a rookie at this, so...  Lesson learned.  Again, thank you very much.  I greatly appreciate it. BTW, I just implemented your fix and I got the correct, desired result.

Comment: Glad it helped. Moving my comment to an answer, since it was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in line 9 of you sample code - you're re-initializing `errdict` as an empty dictionary at every iteration of the `for line...` loop. You want to initialize it at the top of that loop instead i.e. on line 3 of your sample code.